# Gnuplot: How to plot semi circle amplitude graph?

Tags: gnuplot, geometry, amplitude

The title is pretty self explanatory but here is a picture of what I'd like to do. I'm having a tough time figuring out if it's even possible.
[image]

Basically, I have data contains direction from 0 to 180 degree and amplitude each direction. How to make a plot like picture above in gnuplot?

*sample data*:

direction amplitude

0 0.1

2 0.15

etc

180 1.5

Image taken from http://www.imagemet.com/WebHelp6/Default.htm#RoughnessAnalysis/ImageRoughness.htm#kanchor378

Any helps will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: See e.g. [How do I limit a gnuplot polar to a 180 degree range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489353/how-do-i-limit-a-gnuplot-polar-to-a-180-degree-range).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Just wonder, what is zero degree referenced to? North? Is it clock wise or counter clock wise?
How to plot lines from zero to the magnitude (blue lines)?
Sorry for delay response, as I have to make sure everything works.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, I figured it out how to make a that blue lines: 
plot './file.txt' using 1:2 with line notitle,'./file.txt' using $0:$0:1:2 with vectors nohead notitle. Thanks for your assistance Christoph!

Comment: Or use `plot 'file.txt' using 1:2 with impulses notitle`.