# How to start with negative axis polarplot using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

From [How to get a radial(polar) plot using gnu plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772135/how-to-get-a-radialpolar-plot-using-gnu-plot)

My data:

```
theta dB
  0  0.00
 30  0.09
 60 -0.26
 90 -0.26
120 -0.35
150 -0.35
180 -0.35
210 -0.35
240 -0.26
270 -0.09
300 -0.26
330  0.00
360  0.00
```

Axis will not start at 0 but it start at -2 to 0. How can i fix this code?

[image]

Comment: What about a *minimal* script and the output which show your problem?

Comment: my script use follow from that link and i change  set xrange [-1:1] 
set yrange [-1:1]                                                     set xtics (-1,"" -0.5, "" 0, 0.5””, 1)                            set ytics -1, 0.5,1                                                  
http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/xqlka1wvnzsmAwTt

Comment: I know, that you took some code from that link. But it is a long script, and doesn't show your problem. See my answer for a rather short script, like you should have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The range in polar mode is controlled by `set rrange`:

```
set polar
set grid polar
set angles degree
set size ratio 1
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics

set rrange [-2:0]
plot 'file.txt' with lines
```

Result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]